# Elasticsearch---Use the same query return different hits total

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a very simple query to search an index which is last day and has no documents income. but I got a different hits total , I don't know why,I hope some one can help me,My elasticsearch version is 5.5.x .

The query:

```
GET app-wechat-2018.04.16/_search?preference=_primary
  {
    "query": {
         "match": {
            "message": "maidian" 
        }

    }
}
```

one result is like this:

```
{
  "took": 76,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 29579,
    "max_score": 4.108034,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "app-wechat-2018.04.16",
```

...

another result is like this:

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 29582,
    "max_score": 4.1081295,
    "hits": [
     { 
           "_index": "app-wechat-2018.04.16",
```

Comment: Are you sure that no documents are being indexed at the same time in that index?

Comment: @Val yes I am sure!